# PDFBox - find page dimensions

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

How can I find(in mm) the width and the height of a pdf page using PDFBox? Currently, I'm using this:

```
System.out.println(page.getMediaBox().getHeight());
System.out.println(page.getMediaBox().getWidth());
```

but the result is(not in mm):

```
842.0
595.22
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Measurement units inside a PDF are in [points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_(typography)), a traditional graphic industry measurement unit. Adobe uses the following definition:

```
1 pt = 1/72 inch
```

and since one inch is defined to be exactly 25.4 mm (really!), you can convert from points to mm using the formula

```
mm = pt*25.4 / 72
```

Your values, by the way, translate (loosely) to the A4 paper dimensions 210 x 297 mm. ("Loosely", for 2 reasons. First: A*x* dimensions are derived from 1 square meter, in the metric system. Points are based (according to Adobe's usage) in the imperial system; therefore, all conversions between points and millimeters are approximations. Second: the given value in mm for A4 is rounded as well. A*x* relative and absolute sizes are based on [an irrational number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A4_paper#A_series).)

#### Footnote

Inside an object stream, units of measurement can be scaled to something else. The above is only true for top level base objects.

Comment: It's true that those values are approximations. The correct values (rounded to eight decimals) for A4 derived from its definition (a document with a surface of 1/16th of a m²) are 210,22410381mm for width and 297,30177875mm for height. Corresponding values in inches and points are 8,27653952";11,70479444" and 595,91084546pt;842,74519961pt respectively, for the curious.

Comment: PDRectangle source has constants for this calculation: POINTS_PER_INCH = 72; POINTS_PER_MM = 1 / (10 * 2.54f) * POINTS_PER_INCH, also paper sizes like A4,A5, etc

Answer (score 6):

Coordinates in DTP points are defined as: 1 pt = 1/72 inch = 25.4/72 mm

You could write a method like this:

```
public float pt2mm(float pt) {
   return pt * 25.4f / 72;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the document is created using a different DPI than 72 then use the more general formula:

```
public float pt2mmForWeb72dpi(float pt) {
   return pt2mm(pt,72);
}
public float pt2mmForPrint300dpi(float pt) {
   return pt2mm(pt,300);
}
public float pt2mmForPrint600dpi(float pt) {
   return pt2mm(pt,600);
}
public float pt2mm(float pt, float dpi) {
   return pt * 25.4f / dpi;
}
```

You can find more at https://forums.indigorose.com/forum/indigo-rose-software/developer-s-den/13282-what-is-the-size-of-a4-in-px

> A4 is a document format, as a screen image that's going to depend on
>   the image resolution, for example an A4 document resized to:
>
> - 72 dpi (web) = 595 X 842 pixels
> - 300 dpi (print) = 2480 X 3508 pixels
>     (This is "A4" as I know it, i.e. "210mm X 297mm @ 300 dpi")
> - 600 dpi (print) = 4960 X 7016 pixels
>
> And so forth. FWIW document formats like A4 are described by their
>   print dimensions (millimeters), which is a whole different thing than
>   screen images (pixels) so that's why you don't see anyone using pixels
>   to describe A4. :yes

Comment: The PDF default user space units (which this question is about and which default to a pt = 1/72") are completely unrelated to DPI bitmap image resolutions (which your answer is about).

Comment: I added this answer because I had the following problem. I have a pdf produced by a scan in which I found a image of size 2480x3508 pixels and one of 3508x4963. I didn't know how that image size is related to the A4 or A3 page size. After some struggle I realized that both where scanned at 300 dpi and one was an A4 page and the second an A3 page.

Comment: From what I can see of this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55700705/6120066). This answer seems incorrect. Would be interested to hear what @raisercostin thinks.